# opened file can't be seen with lsof

Tags: shell, lsof

I wrote the following scripts(the two scripts are at the same directory),

script A,

```
#!/bin/bash

. B.sh
```

script B,

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "script B..."
read -rsp $'Press enter to continue...\n'
```

After executing script A, I found when 'Press enter to continue...' message displays on the screen, but I still can't see script B is been opening using lsof.

```
lsof +D "/PATH/"
```

Comment: Script *A* doesn't seem to be necessary, *B.sh* run direct from the command line also doesn't show up in `lsof`.

Comment: Do an strace on the invocation of a.sh.  You'll see it opens B.sh, reads it completely, closes it, and then invokes the commands.